# Expected value of a random variable $X$

Tags: probability, random-variables, problem-solving

I am struggling with the two questions of this exercise :

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $ [\![  1, N ]\!] $ the set of natural numbers $k$ such that : $1 \leq k \leq N$. A roulette allows to make the equiprobable drawing of the elements of $ [\![  1, N ]\!] $.

$1)$ Let $p$ be a natural number. $p$ consecutive draws are made using the roulette. Let $X$ be the random variable which indicates the cardinal of the set obtained. Calculate the expected value of $X$

$2)$The drawings of the roulette are repeated until all the whole numbers from $1$ to $N$ have been drawn. Let $Y$ ne the random variable indicating the rank of the stroke. Calculate the expected value of $Y$

I must say that I have completely no ideas of how to proceed for question $2$. Yet for question $1$, I noticed that :

$$P(X = m) = \frac{\binom {N} {m} \cdot (m)^{p-m}}{N^p}$$
Hence if I am not mistaken by the definition of the expected value, we have : 
$$E(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{p} p(X = i) \cdot i$$
Yet as you can see It's seems impossible to get a close form ...

Comment: Check your formua for $P(X=m)$ for small values; say, for $N=3$, $p=2$, $m=2$ your formula gives $P(X=2)=\frac13$. But there are $6$ of $9$ possibilities to draw two different numbers: 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32. Split $X$ into the sum of $N$ random variables equal to the indicators that  a particular number is selected and then use the linearity of Expectation.
What means "rank of the stroke" in the second question?

Comment: Thank you very much ! I am going to try your suggestion :) $Y$ represent the total number of draws I have to do in order to pick all numbers

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem